# fetch class schedule from mind body api

Tags: php

i have two scripts through which i am trying to fetch class schedule from mindbody api. For this i am refereing the documents from github
[devincrossman mindbody api](https://github.com/devincrossman/mindbody-php-api/blob/master/examples/class-schedule-example/index.php)

Code on first page index.php starts from the following code

```
require 'MB_API.php';
$mb = new \DevinCrossman\Mindbody\MB_API(array(
    "SourceName"=>'ABC', 
    "Password"=>'ABC', 
    "SiteIDs"=>array('123')
));
```

and code on second page MB_API.php starts from

```
namespace DevinCrossman\Mindbody;
class MB_API {
    protected $client;
    protected $sourceCredentials = array(
        "SourceName"=>'ABC', 
        "Password"=>'ABC', 
        "SiteIDs"=>array('123')
    );
```

It was working fine, but recently i switched my server and now it is not working, it is supposed to show the schedule of all classes.

now i am getting error

```
Unexpected character in input:  '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 on line 3
syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 3 in index.php (i.e $mb = new \DevinCrossman\Mindbody\MB_API(array()
syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 2 in MB_API.php (i.e namespace DevinCrossman\Mindbody;)
```

Can anyone please tell why this error is present although it used to work fine earlier

Comment: what is your version of PHP? It has to be PHP  > 5.3

Comment: @taliezin it supports 5.2 can u plz tell how i can use it in 5.2

Comment: @roy : it doesn't, https://github.com/devincrossman/mindbody-php-api : "mindbody-php-api,PHP wrapper class for interacting with Mindbody's API via soap. Requires PHP >= 5.3 with SOAP extension."

Comment: @Veve so how can i use this api for my service as i wish to stay on this version only and i am not able to find any other working code to fetch class details

Comment: You can't, or willing to port the library to PHP 5.2, which won't be easy I suppose.